# Convert value to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a large CSV file containing data as follows (I have simplified it):

```
Timestamp,      Value 1, Value 2

41883.00000000, 123.4,   223.4

41883.00011574, 567.8,   667.8
```

I would like to import the data into MSSQL 2008 R2 using SQL Server Import and Export wizard.  To do that, I need to convert my Timestamp column to datetime which will change the Timestamp to :

```
Timestamp ->> Timestamp (converted)

41883.00000000 ->>  2014-09-01 00:00:00

41883.00011574 ->>  2014-09-01 00:00:10
```

Can anyone help me with the syntax to perform this conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These timestamps are in `OADATE` format.

You can just cast from these values to datetime and subtract two days from result:

```
select dateadd(dd, -2, cast(41883.00011574 as datetime))
```

will give you `2014-09-01 00:00:09.997`

You need to subtract two days because SQL server starts at `1900-01-01 00:00:00` and OADATE from `1899-12-30-00:00:00`